# Canakit fan that came with raspberry pi 4 louder then usual

Tags: pi-4, hardware

So I have a raspberry pi 4 running 24/7 (to keep my discord bot running). I noticed recently that the fan that came with it (from Canakit) seems to be louder than usual. Should I be worried? I have it set to normal speed and not slower.

Comment: Does it touch any cables? Is the CPU temperature higher than usual?

Comment: The fan doesn't touch any cables and the temperature feels the same as usual when I touch it

Comment: Then this may indeed indicate that the fan is going to die. A fan that gets louder without obvious case may have its bearings worn out. You should order a new one.

Comment: I don't get this question. If you can get quieter fans elsewhere, and the noise is a problem, then simply don't buy stuff from Canakit.

Comment: Noise isn't the problem. The problem is that it's louder than usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is s strong indication that it is starting to die assuming nothing has moved. Generally it is caused by the lubrication on the berings drying out. Mechanical things that move will fail, we just don't know when or how. I do not know your skill set or resources but I would remove the cover and lubricate the bearings. It generally works but not all the time. The best solution is to follow PMFs solution and purchase a new one. When that comes you can try to lubricate the old one as you would have nothing to lose and maybe a spare. Give user130167's suggestion a try and monitor the temperature. If it cooled enough you have a way of extending the life of your fan.

Answer (score 0):

Put it on the 3.3v low voltage line it will roar like a banshee on the 5v line. This is what I had to do with mine to get a quiet little box like it should be.

Comment: I know about that but I was asking if I should be worried because the fan is louder than usual?